# Tally ERP 9 XML XTTP Data export

Tags: xml, export, xmlhttprequest

I was trying to Export Data from Tally ERP 9 via XML HTTP via localhost:9000. I am getting XML File with ASCII data. This causes many symbols with '?'. Like Ruppee symbol and Euro symbol. Is there any way to export data in Unicode?? The POC used was

```
import httplib
c=httplib.HTTPConnection('localhost:9000')
headers = {"Content-type": "text/xml;charset=UTF-8", "Accept": "text/xml"}
params = """<ENVELOPE>
        <HEADER>
        <TALLYREQUEST>Export Data</TALLYREQUEST>
        </HEADER>
        <BODY>
        <EXPORTDATA>
        <REQUESTDESC>
        <REPORTNAME>List of Accounts</REPORTNAME>
        <STATICVARIABLES>
        <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
        <ACCOUNTTYPE>Ledgers</ACCOUNTTYPE>
        <ENCODINGTYPE>UNICODE</ENCODINGTYPE>
        </STATICVARIABLES>
        </REQUESTDESC>
        </EXPORTDATA>
        </BODY>
        </ENVELOPE>
        """


c.request("POST", "/", params, headers)
r=c.getresponse().read()

fl=file("d:/xtemp.xml","w")
fl.write(r)
fl.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve UNICODE data from Tally ERP 9, you must add the following headers to the HTTP POST request.

**Syntax**

XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader(header, value)

**HTTP Headers to Export Tally data in UNICODE format**

XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader('UNICODE', 'YES')

XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=unicode')

Knowledge base : https://www.rtslink.com

Answer (score 0):

This seems more like an issue with your system fonts rather than Tally.

Make sure you have Rupakara font installed which has the unicode translation for the rupee symbol. Get it [here.](http://www.evertype.com/fonts/rupakara/)